# C# check if unmanaged function pointer is safe before calling

Tags: c#, delegates, unmanaged

I have a singleton in C# that is using `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, and `FreeLibrary` to manually link several functions exported from an unmanaged C++ dll.  Most of the object has declarations that look something like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int Function_prototype(int someParams);
Function_prototype MyFunction;
public myFunction(int someParams)
{
   return MyFunction(someParams);
}
//repeated many times with minor variations for each function
```

And the delegate is assigned using something like this:

```
IntPtr dllHandle = LoadLibrary(@"C:\path\to\file.dll");
IntPtr addressToFunction = GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "MyFunction");
//error checking omitted to keep example brief
MyFunction = (MyFunction_Prototype)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addressToFunction, typeof(MyFunction))
```

(Note: I mention I'm having access violation exceptions in the next paragraph.  They are not related to the above step, it seems to be working correctly and the delegate will be valid for many calls to the function before an access violation happens)

We are trying to diagnose some occasional Access Violation Exceptions that pop up unpredictably when one of these functions is called.  As such, I am exploring solutions to identify the problem before it crashes the whole system.  **I see two approaches, and I need help figuring out how to implement either one, and if both are possible than listing the pros and cons of each would be appreciated.**

1) Is there a way to check if the delegate is no longer valid before the function is called?  I can modify the definition of `myFunction` above to be more like this:

```
public myFunction(int someParams)
{
   try
   {
       return MyFunction(someParams);
   }
   catch(AccessViolationException)
   {
       throw new UsefulErrorException();
   }
}
```

But that would be tedious to add to every function I'm importing.  I looked at the [Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, and its not obvious to me if I can identify that `MyFunction` is invalid before I attempt to call it.  I want something like:

```
if(!MyFunction.IsValid())
    throw new UsefulErrorException();
return MyFunction(someParams);
```

But that is still tedious to write out dozens of times.  Is there an easy way to tell it will fail before it is called?

2) If I have to settle for the `try/catch` example detailed in (1), then is there a way to make it more generic so I don't have to rewrite that try/catch a few dozen times?  It has to be generic enough that I can pass in my unmanaged delegate, its arguments (no `params`, but they contain many different numbers and types of arguments), and various return types (`void`, `int`, `IntPtr`, `string`, `bool`).  I feel like there is a generic approach, otherwise this reeks of violating [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: That is not possible, as soon as you try to fix this problem it will no longer occur.  You must call GCHandle.Alloc() to ensure the delegate cannot be garbage collected.  The GC has no idea whatsoever that the native code is using it.  Do keep in mind how painful LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress is, aim to use [DllImport] whenever possible.  Which does the exact same thing.

Comment: @HansPassant `DllImport` is not an option due to constraints set by those I work for, otherwise I would be.  I am using it to bring in `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, and `FreeLibrary`, but that's it.